# How to connect gremlin with python runtime in GCP environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython

Janusgraph is deployed and running in GCP container, I can access that using Cloud shell.
I want to perform some CRUD operation using python runtime.

What are the connection URL, and ports I have to mention to get proper result.

Docs used to create the GCP environment - https://cloud.google.com/architecture/running-janusgraph-with-bigtable#overview

Docs used to connect gremlin to Python - https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-drivers

But I'm unable to hit the server, Is there anyone out who tried to establish this type of connection.